# Trying to disable the following HTTP Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, TRACE through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm currently running Nikto web scanner on my website. The scanner reported the issue shown in the screenshot. I've been trying to figure how I can disable the following HTTP Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, TRACE through .htaccess

I tried using the following code below but the issue still persists.

```
#Block Unnecassary request methods
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST|OPTIONS|GET|HEAD|TRACE) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

[image: screenshot of web scanner]

Comment: If you disable `GET` and `POST`, how do you expect the website to function?

Comment: Then would this be a a false positive?

Comment: The standard way a browser (or other client) fetches a page is `GET`. You need that, at least, to have a functional website. The standard way a browser submits form data to a site is `POST`. If your site is interactive, you'll need that too. There may possibly be reasons to block `TRACE` and `OPTIONS`, as they reveal some data about how your server is configured.

Comment: The `HEAD` method is basically the same as the `GET` method but with no actual content returned. I don't see a reason to block it.

Comment: So it might be a false positive then. Since it was mentioned in the report. I assumed it was an issue that needs to be resolved and had no idea of the implications

Comment: Even though it might be a false positive is there a way to block it through htaccess so that I may test it

Comment: I think there _is_ a way, but I don't know it (which is why this is a comment, not an answer). At a guess, try what you're currently doing, but leave `GET` (and `POST`, if you have forms).